# FTP Protocol: Server closed connection after some time, why no TIME_WAIT state

Tags: ftp

FTP servers close idle FTP connections automatically after some time and subsequent attempts to download/upload files using this FTP Connection throw FTPConnectionClosedException.

I also observed that the underlying TCP connection used by this FTP connection do not move into TIME_WAIT state before moving into CLOSED state. From FIN_WAIT_2 state, it moves directly to CLOSED state. Whereas my understanding was that from FIN_WAIT_2 state, TCP connections move to TIME_WAIT state first before getting CLOSED.

Though this optimisation of not moving into TIME_WAIT state makes sense(since duplicate packets from previous data connection will no longer be present in the network, as no data has moved through this FTP Connection since a long time and that is why FTP server is also voluntarily closing the connection), but I could not find some reliable information source to confirm this...

Can someone please point me to some good resource to understand the working of FTP protocols...

Thanks

Comment: What you're describing seems to be an implementation-specific feature of the way they've done their idle connection closing. It's not part of the FTP protocol itself.

Comment: Are you sure the server is doing a normal close, and not aborting the connection?

Comment: In my application, I am trying to pull files periodically from the FTP server. I am trying to re-use my FTP connection in these periodic pulls. I observed that the FTP connection gets closed automatically after about 5 minutes.If it's an implementation specific behaviour of   my FTP server, then moving to TIME_WAIT state may or may not be true. In case we do move to TIME_WAIT state, for some time that host/port pair of my FTP server will be unavailable. If I want to get new FTP connection during this time, I can get ConnectionRefusedException

Comment: The `TIME_WAIT` state is for an entire `<localip, localport, remoteip, remoteport>` tuple. Each connection to local port 21 will have a different `remoteip` and/or `remoteport`, so there shouldn't be a problem establishing a new connection.

Comment: As I understand, TIME_WAIT state is not for the entire <localip, localport, remoteip, remoteport> tuple, but is for the FTPServer's <port, host> tuple only.
Please correct me if i am wrong...

Comment: I am trying to re-use FTP connection while pulling files periodically from FTP server.
If closing connection after 5 mins is an implementation specific behaviour of my FTP server, then moving to TIME_WAIT state may or may not be true.
In case TCP connection at server side does move to TIME_WAIT state, that host/pair of my FTP server will remain unavailable for some time.

If I want to get new FTP connection during this time, I can possibly get ConnectionRefusedException if all other ports are already occupied by other FTP connections to this server.
How should we tackle these scenarios ???

Comment: Unless you've recently opened thousands of connections to the same server from this client, you won't use up all the local ports.

Comment: Thanks Barmer for helping me with this problem.
I am reusing FTP connection only if the connection is still open.
My problem is that in case connection is closed and i try to open a new connection, since the last host/pair of the FTP server may be in TIME_WAIT state, server may refuse this new connection request...
How should be handle such situations....

Comment: Every connection you make to the server should use a different, ephemeral local port. So there shouldn't be any conflict.

Comment: You need to post your code. If you're making a mistake in how you open the connection, we can show you how to fix it.

Comment: There will not be a problem in case total no. of FTP connections on that machine are low, but I have observed that most FTP servers do not allow a total of more than a few FTP connections (e.g. 25 in the case of my FTP server). In such cases after making 25 connections, you tend to get ConnectionRefusedExeption... in case previously closed connection is still in TIME_WAIT state

Comment: If that's the way the server works, there's not much you can do about it on the client. The best thing to do is close the control connection before the server does.

Comment: My FTP server didn't allow more than 25 connections, so its not that thousands of FTP connections are allowed by FTP servers in general, and hence this problem is rare.
In my case, this problem occurs quite frequently

Comment: Closing connection at client side will not help because FTP server's TCP connection will still move into TIME_WAIT state (because of the way TCP connections work) causing the same problem...
Can you please point me to some good tutorial on FTP. I am unable to find one....
Thanks

Comment: That's not a TCP limit, that's just preventing server overloading by limiting the number of concurrent clients.

Comment: I'm not sure there are any tutorials that will address the issues you're asking about, but try: http://tcpipguide.com/free/t_FileTransferProtocolFTP.htm